# where is the return statement written when using a for loop and arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

so that code i am sending inputs from the main method to a method to do a calculation and i want to return the array values back again

```
gross[i] = process_g(rate, hours, overtime, emp_num);
```

and in the `process_g` method i wrote that

```
 public static double process_g(double rate[], double hours[],double overtime[], int emp_num)
 {
  for(int i = 0; i < emp_num; i++)
  {
   return (rate[i] * hours[i]) + overtime[i];
  }
 }
```

but it keep giving me error that there is a missing return statement and i tried to edit it and make it like that

```
 {
  double ret = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < emp_num; i++)
  {
   ret = (rate[i] * hours[i]) + overtime[i];
  }
  return ret;
 }
```

that made the programm work but it gives me 0 for the first array in the `gross[i]`

Comment: what's your question? return value is dependent on your input...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do... why does your initial solution return in the for loop? What is process_g supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean to return a `double` or a `double[]`?

Comment: @Ecto **but it keep giving me error that there is a missing return statement and i tried to edit it and make it like that**

Comment: @robinsax `process_g` is a method to calculate `(rate[i] * hours[i]) + overtime[i];` and i want to return the value and store it in the array `gross[i]`

Comment: @khelwood sorry that was my mistake. i want to return `double[]`

Comment: Then your method needs to have return type `double[]`, and you need to write a return statement that returns an array, not a single value.

Comment: @MuhammadArafa you are getting error because it's never certain if your code will ever step into the loop and every function must have return value (if it's not void). Is that answer to your "question" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to return an array of double, then it needs to have return type `double[]`, and you need to write a return statement that returns an array, not a single value.

Maybe something like this is what you're after:

```
public static double[] process_g(double rate[], double hours[],
                                 double overtime[], int emp_num) {
    double[] result = new double[emp_num];
    for (int i = 0; i < emp_num; i++) {
        result[i] = (rate[i] * hours[i]) + overtime[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
double[] gross = process_g(rate, hours, overtime, emp_num);
```

Comment: another problem appeared, i get that error **cannot find symbol** the symbol is `gross` as i am sending the returned gross value to another method by using this code `output(emp_num, hours, rate, overtime, gross);` and the method is `public static void output(int emp_num, double hours[], double rate[], double overtime[], double gross[])`

Comment: Sounds like you have a new problem and you should ask a new question with a [mre].